# xQuery: test for two specific children with 'and'

Tags: conditional-statements, xquery

Assume I have the following snippet

```
<persName>
    <forename>Gaius</forename>
    <surname>Iulius</surname>
    <addName>Caesar</addName>
</persName>
```

I need a result like `[surname], [forename]` where the comma should only be present if necessary.

In XSLT, I'd simply use

```
<xsl:value-of select="surname" />
<xsl:if test="surname and forename"><xsl:text>, </xsl:text></xsl:if>
<xsl:value-of select="forename" />
```

Now I naively thought I could transfer this to XQuery – and failed.
I was slightly puzzled that

```
if ($node/forename) then "1" else "0"
if ($node/surname) then "1" else "0"
if ($node/surname and $node/forename) then "1" else "0"
```

will give `1`, `1`, `0`, respectively.
I worked around this by counting the number of children in one of these cases but I'm still puzzled why this is the way it is.

Tanks for any input!

---

Edit: here's the code I've been using:

```
declare function habe:shortName($node) {
    <span>{
        if ($node/tei:name) then $node/tei:name
        else 
            let $tr := if ($node/tei:surname and count($node/tei:forename)>0) then ", " else ""
            return concat($node/tei:surname, $tr, $node/tei:forename)
    }</span>
};
```

which, when given the above snippet, returned `IuliusGaius`.

I then tried the three tests above and got the stated result.

I'm doing this on eXist – maybe their implementation is faulty?

---

Edit: Thanks to @MichaelKay and @joewiz for hinting at misleading typos!

Comment: Your result is unexpected, so I suspect an error in your code. You will need to post an example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've added the code that I originally ran.

Comment: Your XML snippet is not well-formed, and your use of namespace prefixes is inconsistent.

Comment: There's a much simpler solution in XSLT: `<xsl:value-of select="surname, forename" separator=", "/>`

Comment: Since you misspelled "forename" in your XSLT example, perhaps you misspelled it in one of your XQuery examples as well?

Comment: @joewiz: What I typed here is indeed wrong, it should of course be `<addName>Caesar</addName>` – this was simply a typo on my part here as I didn't copy&paste. The data in the DB is of course well formed.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Thanks for your XSLT hint!I surely read that some time and completely forgot about it.
I rechecked the spelling in my XQuery and it's okay there (one of the cases, copy&paste would have been better than typing).

Comment: @dariok: Sure, everyone makes typos. I reported it so you could edit your post, so that others trying to help you will not encounter the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to your original problem (adding a `', '` if both `forename` and `surname` exist) is to use `string-join($strs as xs:string*, $joiner as xs:string)` instead of `concat($string as xs:string[...])`:

```
let $name :=
    <persName>
        <forename>Gaius</forename>
        <surname>Iulius</surname>
        <addName>Caesar</addName>
    </persName>
return string-join(($name/surname, $name/forename), ', ')
```

This returns `Iulius, Gaius`.

You can also check for presence of nodes directly in boolean expressions:

```
let $name :=
    <persName>
        <forename>Gaius</forename>
        <surname>Iulius</surname>
        <addName>Caesar</addName>
    </persName>
return (
  $name/surname and $name/forename,
  $name/surname and $name/foo
)
```

This returns `true false`.

Answer (score 2):

The following code returns the expected results, `(1, 1, 1)`, using eXide on http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/eXide/index.html:

```
xquery version "3.0";

let $node := 
    <persName>
        <forename>Gaius</forename>
        <surname>Iulius</surname>
        <addName>Caesar</addName>
    </persName>
return
    (
        if ($node/forename) then "1" else "0",
        if ($node/surname) then "1" else "0",
        if ($node/surname and $node/forename) then "1" else "0"
    )
```

Comment: Can you think of anything that might interfere? Cf. my test output at http://dev2.hab.de:8080/exist/edoc/test.xql which gives you one XML snippet and also shows you the XQuery behind it. Please correct me if I got something completely mixed up.

Comment: I come closer to thinking that there is some bug in eXist. I have just been brooding over sth similar: given a node `tei:person/tei:listPlace/tei:bibl`, `($node/ancestor::tei:person or $node/ancestor::tei:place)` evaluates false while `($node/ancestor::tei:person)` evaluates true as does `($node/ancestor::tei:person or count($node/ancestor::tei:place)>0)`.

Comment: If there is a bug, it's not present in my version of eXist - a build of the develop branch from about May. What version of eXist are you using? Here are some tests I created to see if I was affected or not - but I got the expected results, not what you're seeing: https://gist.github.com/joewiz/458d7fd68d348556b6976b2e199add4f

Comment: Thanks for testing. I'm on the RC2, 3rd August. Something odd is going on here: your test work here, as well, so I've added some of my own: https://gist.github.com/dariok/a4feb9ee14d58dff6aed0a2268cdf6d3 on my machine results in http://dev2.hab.de:8080/exist/edoc/test/test3.xql – note that `dariok[@type='ondisk']` is not `false` but simply empty.

Comment: Probably best to continue this by opening an issue at https://github.com/exist-db/exist/issues?